# Show Fragment after send Data to other Fragment

Tags: c#, xamarin, fragment

my problem is to switch the Fragment to other Fragment.
The Data was forwarded and all other work´s.

For Example: Start is bei MainActivity, this has four Fragment in an external ViewPagerAdapter.
On Fragment Three is a DataSource and gave a Feedback to Fragmant Two, is fine and Work, but is see further the Three Fragment not the Secound.

Fragment Three:
     base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
        if (resultCode == 1)
        {
            string storageString = data.GetStringExtra(IntentManager.ViewModel);
            MapViewFragment mapViewFragment = KartenViewFragment.NewInstance(1, "Frag2");
            FragmentTransaction transaction = ((Activity)Context).SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("storageString", storageString);
            transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.Kartenlayout, mapViewFragment);
            transaction.AddToBackStack(null);
            transaction.Commit();
            MapViewFragment.Arguments = bundle;
        }
```

Fragment Two:

```
 View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment_Karte, container, false);
        if (Arguments != null)
        {
            string storageString = Arguments.GetString("storageString");
            if (storageString != null)
            {
                do something !!!
            }
        }
```

I don´t no how is the problem, anyone a solution ?

Comment: When switching fragment , you can use `onHiddenChanged` to refresh data .

Comment: Thank for it, i go and check this.